# How to change soap address at end of wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf

I have a WSDL that is being generated by Apache CXF WS that looks like this

```
<wsdl:service name="MyWS">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:MyWSSoapBinding" name="MyWSImplPort">
        <soap:address location="http://someaddress/MyApp/ws/MyWS"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

I would like to change the `soap:address` to have the protocol of `https` instead of `http`.

The reason behind this need. We are running a SpringBootApp on a tomcat server behind a LoadBalancer. The load balancer will receive the request on address `https://someaddress/MyApp/ws/MyWs?wsdl` and then forwards the request to the server through `http`. When the wsdl is autogenerated by Apache CXF, it is generating it with the soap:address with the protocol of `http` instead of `https`.

In the Application.java

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
   CXFServlet servlet = new CXFServlet();
   return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/MyApp/ws/*");
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public Endpoint submitAssessment(ApplicationContext context, MyWS myWS) {
   Bus cxfBus = (Bus)context.getBean(Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID);
   EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(cxfBus, myWS);
   endpoint.setAddress("/MyWS");
   cxfBus.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
   endpoint.publish();
   return endpoint;
}
```

On my Service implementation

```
@Service
@WebService(serviceName = "MyWS", name = "MyWSPortType", portName = "MyWSPort", )
public class MyWSImpl implements MyWS {
```

Comment: did you try endpoint.setPublishedEndpointUrl("https ://someaddress/MyApp/ws/MyWS");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter "publishedEndpointURL" looks like the one you're searching for.

See:
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-configuration.html